# Load document returned by AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, document

I am working on a Django app and I'm having an issue with ajax and jQuery.

On my page, I have a javascript function that is called when a button is clicked. The purpose of this function is to make an ajax
call to a django view method. In this method some logic is done using some POST data which was sent with the AJAX call, and if the operation was successful, I want to return to 
another page, otherwise, I simply want the user to remain on the same page, and a notice will be presented to the user using javascript.

below is a snippet of code:

(Javascript)

```
function makeCall() {

    $.post(url, data, function(data) {

          if(data=="ERROR") {

             alert("THERE WAS AN ERROR");

          } else {

             //send user to a new page. 
          }
    });
}
```

(Django-Python)

```
def viewMethod(request):

   //LOGIC...  Renders page using POST data.

    if success:

        //... preparing the response.

        return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
    else:

        return HttpResponse("ERROR", content_type="text/plain")
```

How can I present the response page to the user using javascript/jQuery in the case that the operation is a success?

Thanks

Comment: `window.location.href =`

Comment: Sorry, I missed some details in my original question, it is now updated. This did not work because the page is being generated using some POST data which was sent in the AJAX call. The method is returning a full html document, not just a url. I understand that with GET I could return a url string with the necessary arguments to generate the page, but for this case I must use POST. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the viewMethod, you can render page using POST data but not the whole page, that is ,the page you will respond just has the body tags not the head.

```
if success:
    return HttpResponse('<body><p>SUCCESS</p></body>')
```

and in front-end

```
$.post(url, data, function(data) {

      if(data=="ERROR") {

         alert("THERE WAS AN ERROR");

      } else {

         $('tip').append(data)
      }
});
```

if you still use the whole page, its formal like this: , you can use window.open or iframe tag to handle it.
But I advise just respond some snippets of html.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's some peculiarity in Django, there should be nothing to prevent a POST request behaving differently from a GET request. Both should be capable of returning a URL string.

If you would prefer to receive a URL and replace the current document, then try the following :

```
function makeCall(url, data) {
    function newPageError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    }
    $.post(url, data).success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if(!data.match(/^http/)) {
            newPageError(jqXHR, data, textStatus + ' - but error indicated');
        } else {
            location.href = data;
            //location.replace(data);//alternative; gives different Back button behaviour
        }
    }).fail(newPageError);
}
```

Alternatively, if you would prefer to receive an HTML snippet and work within the current document, then try the following :

```
function makeCall(url, data) {
    function newPageError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    }
    $.post(url, data).success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if(data.toUpperCase() == 'ERROR') {
            newPageError(jqXHR, 'ERROR', textStatus + ' - but error indicated');
        } else {
            $("#myDiv").html(data); //change jQuery selector to suit
        }
    }).fail(newPageError);
}
```

Notes:

- In both cases, two types of error are handled; an error indicated in a successful response, and a total HTTP error (eg internal server error).
- In both cases, it is assumed the url, `url`, and query parameters, `data`, are passed to the function.
- In the first case, the server-side script would need to be modified to return a URL.